# performance of a regression model

Tags: machine-learning

I am doing random forest regression for multiple features. Now I want to know my model performance. But there is no confusion matrix or accuracy matrix for checking regression model performance.
So how can i check my model performance for this regression problem?

Comment: You could try measures like (root) mean squared error, mean absolute error, etc. Searching for "regression error metric" should lead you to plenty of useful resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could help you further if you detail your application and language in which you are implementing your regression.

I did not understand why there is no *confusion matrix* to evaluate your results. I suppose you have some data that you are using to train your *random forest*, so the best practice would be to split it into a training and a testing set. If you are using python/pandas, you can do this as follow:

```
## Considering your dataset has 1000 samples and you'll split it into 70%-30% 
training_set = dataset.sample(700)
testing_set = dataset.drop(labels=training_set.index)
```

Once you've split your data, you can use some libraries both for fitting your model as well as checking its accuracy. [Here](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/random-forest-regression-9871bc9a25eb) you'll find an example in python of a random forest implementation using cross-validation to check its accuracy.

Regardless of which language you are implementing, an alternative is to use R-squared as a performance metric (remember that in all cases, you will need a reference, so separating your dataset into a training and testing part is extremely important).

As detailed in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/metrics-ml-2563f9e47faa):

> The coefficient of determination (R-Squared) quantifies how good the
>   simulation is compared to a baseline model with no independent
>   variables that always predicts the expected value of y. Mainly used in
>   regression, one-to-one comparisons between the predicted value and
>   ground truth value.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to check the performance of a linear regression. Probably the most common is $R^2$ but there is also adjusted $R^2$, root mean square error, mean absolute error, mean absolute percentage error (MAPE) and others.

I also like to take graphical approaches and graph the predicted values against the actual values in various ways - a scatter plot, a Tukey mean difference plot (aka Bland Altman plot), a box plot of the residuals and so on.

Comment: Is there something like adjusted $R^2$ for a random forest?